# Cannot edit Manager field in Active Directory using LDAP in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm using this function to set the properties of a new user in AD

```
Public Shared Sub SetProperty(ByVal de As DirectoryEntry, Byval pName As String, ByVal pValue As String)
If Not pValue is Nothing Then
     If de.Properties.Contains(pName) Then
        de.Properties(pName)(0) = pValue
Else
        de.Properties(pName).Add(Value)
     End If
End If
```

End Sub

Then I call the function using

```
Dim adUsers As DirectoryEntries = dirEntry.Children
Dim newUser As DirectoryEntry = adUsers.Add("CN=" Username, "user")

SetProperty(newUser, "manager", Username)
```

This works for all properties except for manager. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: The application coder should check whether the authentication ID used has permission to modify the entry, and especially whether the authentication ID has permission to modify the `manager` attribute using a known good command line tool called `ldapmodify`. For more information, see ["Using ldapmodify"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/).

Comment: The authentication ID does have permission to modify the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Manager is expecting a distinguishedName.  You would need something in the format of "cn=username,ou=UserAccountsOu,dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com"

Also, I've never tested setting a user as his own manager, AD may not allow that.